# Compile PHP by source. Stuck at phar.phar

Tags: software-installation, php, source

I am trying to install PHP (Version - 5.5.11) by source since I need php installation with `enable-debug` and `enable-maintainer-zts` options.

- Downloaded the package
- `./configure --enable-maintainer-zts --enable-debug  --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql`
- and when I do make, the steps are all fine until I reach "Generating phar.phar" where the make seems to be stuck

On inspecting (with make -n) the steps to be run are,

```
echo "Generating phar.phar"
rm -f ext/phar/phar.phar
rm -f /usr/local/PHP_5.5.11_INSTALLATION/php-5.5.11/ext/phar/phar.phar
` if test -x "/usr/local/PHP_5.5.11_INSTALLATION/php-5.5.11/sapi/cli/php"; then /usr/local/PHP_5.5.11_INSTALLATION/php-5.5.11/build/shtool echo -n -- "/usr/local/PHP_5.5.11_INSTALLATION/php-5.5.11/sapi/cli/php -n"; if test "x" != "x"; then /usr/local/PHP_5.5.11_INSTALLATION/php-5.5.11/build/shtool echo -n -- " -d extension_dir=/usr/local/PHP_5.5.11_INSTALLATION/php-5.5.11/modules"; for i in bz2 zlib phar; do if test -f "/usr/local/PHP_5.5.11_INSTALLATION/php-5.5.11/modules/$i.la"; then . /usr/local/PHP_5.5.11_INSTALLATION/php-5.5.11/modules/$i.la; /usr/local/PHP_5.5.11_INSTALLATION/php-5.5.11/build/shtool echo -n -- " -d extension=$dlname"; fi; done; fi; else /usr/local/PHP_5.5.11_INSTALLATION/php-5.5.11/build/shtool echo -n -- "/usr/local/PHP_5.5.11_INSTALLATION/php-5.5.11/sapi/cli/php"; fi;` -d 'open_basedir=' -d 'output_buffering=0' -d 'memory_limit=-1' -d phar.readonly=0 -d 'safe_mode=0' ext/phar/phar.php pack -f ext/phar/phar.phar -a pharcommand -c auto -x \\.svn -p 0 -s /usr/local/PHP_5.5.11_INSTALLATION/php-5.5.11/ext/phar/phar/phar.php -h sha1 -b "`/usr/local/PHP_5.5.11_INSTALLATION/php-5.5.11/build/shtool echo -n -- "/usr/local/bin/php";`"  /usr/local/PHP_5.5.11_INSTALLATION/php-5.5.11/ext/phar/phar/
chmod +x ext/phar/phar.phar
echo
echo "Build complete."
echo "Don't forget to run 'make test'."
echo
```

I ran the command manually and in `ps aux` I see,

```
 /usr/local/PHP_5.5.11_INSTALLATION/php-5.5.11/sapi/cli/php -n -d open_basedir= -d output_buffering=0 -d memory_limit=-1 -d phar.readonly=0 -d safe_mode=0 ext/phar/phar.php pack -f ext/phar/phar.phar -a pharcommand -c auto -x \.svn -p 0 -s /usr/local/PHP_5.5.11_INSTALLATION/php-5.5.11/ext/phar/phar/phar.php -h sha1 -b /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/PHP_5.5.11_INSTALLATION/php-5.5.11/ext/phar/phar/
```

and another command invoked by this command,

```
 sh -c cd '/usr/local/PHP_5.5.11_INSTALLATION/php-5.5.11' ; pear -q info PHP_Archive 2>/dev/null|grep 'API Version'
```

From what I see, `pear` is a directory in the php folder. So what is happening here? Why are arguments being passed to it?

Have I missed some step ? Do I need to install PEAR or something?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to implement difficult compilation methods. You can install php 5.5 by using [**ppa:ondrej/php5**](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5) repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install <NEEDED PACKAGE1> <NEEDED PACKAGE2>
```

Comment: Will I be able to the swicthes I need during installation? The options I need are generally disabled by default